# Transaction manager definition for Spring Integration JMS endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, dsl

In Spring Integration XML DSL is ability to specify transaction manager for JMS message-driven channel adapter:

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="..."
        connection-factory="..." destination="..."
        channel="..." error-channel="errorChannel"
        transaction-manager="processTransactionManager" auto-startup="false"/>
```

How to add transaction manager to my exist [SI Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/spring-integration-java-dsl-reference)

```
Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(...)
                .destination(...)
                .outputChannel(...)
                .errorChannel(errorChannel)
                .autoStartup(false)
                .get();
```

I wouldn't not use `Jms.channel(...)` DSL call here cause I have to rework my exit flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(
        Jms.container(this.jmsConnectionFactory, ...)
            .transactionManager(...)
            .get())
```

There is `Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter()` to accept `AbstractMessageListenerContainer` implementation and as you see top-level builder from the `Jms.container()` factory.

**UPDATE**

For SI Java DSL `1.1.x` the workaround is like:

1. Use `Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(AbstractMessageListenerContainer)`
2. Configure top-level `@Bean` for the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`
3. And use its `setTransactionManager()`

Comment: Thank you, but in my SI `1.1.2.RELEASE` version there is no `transactionManager` method. What version I should use?

Comment: Well, thank you can `JmsListenerContainerSpec.get()` and call `setTransactionManager()`. Consider to upgrade to `1.2`: https://spring.io/blog/2016/10/14/java-dsl-for-spring-integration-1-2-release-is-available. (you didn't mention the version in your question...)

Comment: I couldn't use the solution with simple upgrade to `1.2.0` version cause it requires upgrading of other Springs' libs to `4.3.4` and such upgrade brings us other problems in our code. So is it possible to specify `transactionManager` in `1.1.2.RELEASE` somehow?

Comment: I said you: `JmsListenerContainerSpec.get()` and call `AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.setTransactionManager()` directly. You still can specify any other options to the `spec`. What other problems do you have with `SI-4.3.4` ?

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Smth inside Hibernate initialization + our corporate Nexus repo doesn't have full set the latest Spring libs.

Comment: Got it! So did you understand that the workaround for your use-case is regular `@Bean` for the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following snippet

```
@Bean
PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return new JmsTransactionManager(connectionFactory);
}

@Bean
JmsInboundGateway jmsInboundGateway(
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
    MessageChannel errorChannel,
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {

    return Jms
        .inboundGateway(
            Jms.container(connectionFactory, "process-input")
                .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                .get()
            )
        .requestChannel(processingInputChannel())
        .defaultReplyQueueName("process-output")
        .replyChannel(processingOutputChannel())
        .errorChannel(errorChannel)
        .get();
}
```